# How to return column that will be sorted by number within component in React Table?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a table with React Table library and I don't know how to format returning number for cells and to have working sorting by numbers. When I return something different that number sorting is no longer working as expected It works by alphabetical order not by numerical.

One of columns:

```
{
    Header: "Ocena",
    accessor: row => {
      const votes = row["usersVote"].reduce(
        (acc, r) => acc + (r.vote === "up" ? 1 : -1),
        0
      );

      return (
        votes > 0 && (
          <StyledVote color="rgb(48, 131, 115)">
            +{Number(votes)}
          </StyledVote>
        )
      );

      return votes;
    },
```

When I comment out returning of component and leave only `return: votes` sorting is working properly. How to return a component and have fully working sorting by numerical order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer.

accessor function is calling before data is moved to the table and in that place we should prepare our data to be sortable (in my case I need numbers):

```
accessor: row => +row['usersVote']
```

And later when we want to render that data in other way we need to call Cell function

```
Cell: row => <NumberComponent row={row} />
```

And do whatever you want to do with that data

Source: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options